# Set null (default) if array element is undefined

Tags: php

I have a function to populate an Object.

```
public static function populateObj($data) {
    $obj = new Obj();
    $obj->setVal1($data['val1']);
    $obj->setVal2($data['val2']);
    $obj->setId($data['id']);
    return $obj;
}
```

If all values are given with the parameter `$data` it works fine. But if someting is missing it throws an error.
Is there a shorter and easier or better way to set `null` as default than this:

```
$data['val1'] ? $obj->setVal1($data['val1']) : $obj->setVal1(null);
...
```

Comment: should be `!empty($data['val1']) ? $obj->setVal1($data['val1']) : $obj->setVal1(null)`  or `isset($data['val1']) ? $obj->setVal1($data['val1']) : $obj->setVal1(null)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can merge with a default array, then `$data` will contain all of those keys:

```
$data = array_merge(['val1'=>null, 'val2'=>null, 'id'=>null], $data);
```

In PHP >= 7.0 you can use the [Null Coalescing Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce):

```
$obj->setVal1($data['val1'] ?? null);
```

Answer (score 2):

That is perhaps the fastest (fewest typed words) way to do it.  Another that may be faster, if it is worth it to you is to make a class and a constructor with `default values`.  `array_pad()` with `array_merge()` may also be worth looking at, depending on your application.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 7+ you can use `??` *a.k.a null coalesce*

```
$obj->setVal1($data['val1']??null);
$obj->setVal2($data['val2']??null);
$obj->setId($data['id']??null);
```

See an example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae8efd9cd967d71bda629ae26d10e77ae98b3dee)

> The null coalescing operator (??) has been added (in PHP7) as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.